# Resample df with 1/10 of a year instead of daily, monthly etc

Tags: python, r, pandas, data-manipulation, timedelta

I have a large csv file with recordings of over 20 years for about 100 different brands. an example of the original data contained in csv file and grouped by year looks like below.

```
name                year    value
brand1             2000     3
brand2             2000     3
brand3             2000     1
brand4             2000     0
brand5             2000     3
brand6             2000     1
brand7             2000     1
brand8             2000     3
brand9             2000     1
brand10            2000     3
brand11            2000     1
brand12            2000     0
brand13            2000     0
brand14            2000     3
brand15            2000     3
brand16            2000     0
brand17            2000     0
brand18            2000     0
brand19            2000     1
brand20            2000     0

brand1             2001     6
brand2             2001     4
brand3             2001     2
brand4             2001     1
brand5             2001     4
brand6             2001     2
brand7             2001     4
brand8             2001     4
brand9             2001     1
brand10            2001     6
brand11            2001     4
brand12            2001     0
brand13            2001     0
brand14            2001     3
brand15            2001     4
brand16            2001     1
brand17            2001     0
brand18            2001     0
brand19            2001     4
brand20            2001     3
```

I am able to resample it to daily, monthly, quarterly etc.
After struggling for the third day now i still cannot be able to group my data by name and resample it using 1/10 of a year and then interpolate the value column.

Below is an example of the final output data desired.

```
name           year          value
brand1         1999          0.0
brand1         1999.1        0.3
brand1         1999.2        0.6
brand1         1999.3        0.9
brand1         1999.4        1.2
brand1         1999.5        1.5
brand1         1999.6        1.8
brand1         1999.7        2.1
brand1         1999.8        2.4
brand1         1999.9        2.7
brand1         2000          3.0

brand1         2000          3.0
brand1         2000.1        3.3
brand1         2000.2        3.6
brand1         2000.3        3.9
brand1         2000.4        4.2
brand1         2000.5        4.5
brand1         2000.6        4.8
brand1         2000.7        5.1
brand1         2000.8        5.4
brand1         2000.9        5.7
brand1         2001          6.0
```

I would like all of the data in my csv look like this.

On many trial using TimedeltaIndex its has bore no fruits.

is there a way i can interpolate using any other method or using the timedeltaindex in pandas to achieve the required results.

I want my data presented in this format since any alteration to resampling will cost me long time to revise a code i have already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in R, using `library(data.table)` we can do

```
dt[dt[, .(year = seq.int(year[1], year[.N], 0.1)), by=name], on=c('year', 'name')][, 
  value := zoo::na.approx(value, na.rm = FALSE)]
```

Which gives

```
#         name   year value
# 1:    brand1 2000.0   3.0
# 2:    brand1 2000.1   3.3
# 3:    brand1 2000.2   3.6
# 4:    brand1 2000.3   3.9
# 5:    brand1 2000.4   4.2
# ---                     
# 216: brand20 2000.6   1.8
# 217: brand20 2000.7   2.1
# 218: brand20 2000.8   2.4
# 219: brand20 2000.9   2.7
# 220: brand20 2001.0   3.0
```

The data:

```
dt = fread("
name               year    value
brand1             2000     3
brand2             2000     3
brand3             2000     1
brand4             2000     0
brand5             2000     3
brand6             2000     1
brand7             2000     1
brand8             2000     3
brand9             2000     1
brand10            2000     3
brand11            2000     1
brand12            2000     0
brand13            2000     0
brand14            2000     3
brand15            2000     3
brand16            2000     0
brand17            2000     0
brand18            2000     0
brand19            2000     1
brand20            2000     0
brand1             2001     6
brand2             2001     4
brand3             2001     2
brand4             2001     1
brand5             2001     4
brand6             2001     2
brand7             2001     4
brand8             2001     4
brand9             2001     1
brand10            2001     6
brand11            2001     4
brand12            2001     0
brand13            2001     0
brand14            2001     3
brand15            2001     4
brand16            2001     1
brand17            2001     0
brand18            2001     0
brand19            2001     4
brand20            2001     3"
)
```